# Achievements I should know before I start Final Fantasy XIII

Tags: xbox-360, achievements, final-fantasy-13

I recently picked up Final Fantasy XIII for the 360 and I wanted to know if there are any achievements I should know about a head of time so I don't screw up and have to play through again.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The two you want to watch out for are the following:

- **Loremaster** (Discerned the full attributes of 100 enemies.): just make sure you use *Libra* multiple times on enemies until all attributes are filled out (no question marks). There are way more than 100 enemies in the game, but some enemies only appear in one chapter, which is really annoying if you're trying to be a completionist.
- **Treasure Hunter** (Held every weapon and accessory): make sure you <strike>equip every item before you sell it, and</strike> don't sell weapons, even if you think they're junk. You don't want to sell weapons because you'll need to upgrade at each weapon at least once (upgrading creates a new item) to get the achievement.

The rest of the achievements you'll get as you progress through the game, or can be completed once you complete the game. Some of the achievements can only realistically be done after you complete the game.

Comment: I don't think you need to equip every item to get that achievement (according to what I've read, didn't go through it myself). Not selling anything is definately good advice though, I think some items rely on things being dismantled as well possibly?

Comment: Loremaster's easy pretty easy. I didn't know you had to equip them for Treasure HunTer though. I thought you  just had to hold them since it says that. =/

Comment: Loremaster's easy, but it threw me for a loop because *Libra* in past iterations of Final Fantasy exposed all stats when you first use it. In FF13, it can take 2 or 3 casts before you get all the stats.

Comment: Earlier, I had said in the answer and a comment that you needed to equip the items for the achievement: you guys are right and I was wrong; you only need to have owned them. Regarding dismantling, it's not necessary to get all the accessories or the components to upgrade weapons.

Answer (score 1):

Check it out at [Xbox360achievements.com](http://Xbox360achievements.com)

It lists all Secret Achievement also, so don't scroll down to far if you don't want to know.

[Final Fantasy XIII](http://www.xbox360achievements.org/game/final-fantasy-xiii/achievements/)

If you click the Achievement guide tab it will give you a full description on how to get each achievement.

Comment: I think he's asking more which achievements he needs to know ahead of time, so he won't miss one, but still doesn't have the majority spoiled.

Comment: Ok. I realize I was giving a more wide ranged answer now. Its still an option. I have not played Final Fantasy XIII myself, but this is how I would find out about the achievements to achieve before hand.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the list that Tricky posted, they look like the same ones as on the PS3. I don't believe it's possible to make any of them unachievable. I skipped some of the less-linear parts, but you can still come back later if it was important.

Comment: Maybe not unachievable, but less annoying.  If there was an achievement to kill 1000 enemies with a chainsaw thats the kind of thing where I want to start killing enemies at day 1, instead of finding out after the final boss and then going to find 900 enemies.

Comment: Yeah, true enough.